# Actionscript 3 equivalent of KeyboardEvent.Repeat

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard-events, adobe-animate

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to programming; I'm doing a flash game for my 2D Game class on Adobe Animator, and I had a doubt about the code that my instructor couldn't answer himself. Long story short, I want the character speed to increase based on how long the key has been pressed, so I came up with this:

```
spdX = spdX + aclMov*(tempo) - aclFrc*(tempo);
```

Where the variable tempo would increase as long as the key is being held down, and I would check if it is with KeyboardEvent.repeat, as in:

```
if(heldDown){while(heldDown){tempo += 1}}
else{tempo = 0}

spdX = spdX + aclMov*(tempo) - aclFrc*(tempo);
```

However when I try to do that, the output responds with "*Property repeat not found on flash.events.KeyboardEvent and there is no default value*". I assume that this is because KeyboardEvent.repeat is not defined in the medium I'm using. Is there anyway I can reproduce the *same effect* of KeyboardEvent.repeat, perhaps by creating a function that mimics what it would have done?

Thanks in advance.

(Edit 1)

I begin apologizing for my shortness of clarification, as well as my ignorance in the topic as I am barely a beginner when it comes to as3, and am not properly presented yet to many of the terms I've read.

So, thanks to the meaningful contributions of comments, I already have been given a glimpse of what kind of workaround I would need to do to substitute KeyboardEvent.repeat. There are other parts of the code of relevance to the problem, as well:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressKey)

function pressKey (Event){
(...)
if(Event.keyCode == (Keyboard.A)) {left = true;}
(...)
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,releaseKey)

function releaseKey (Event){
(...)
if(Event.keyCode == (Keyboard.A)) {left = false;}
(...)
}
```

This is how the code was intended to go. It was suggested that I use the getTimer() method to record the moment the event **KEY_DOWN** happens, stopping when the **KEY_UP** comes into effect. Problem is, how can I increment the code to make it differentiate between those two events, and more specifically, *how can I adapt the **ENTER_FRAME** event so that differentiating between them still works with it?* Here's the most relevant parts of it, by the way:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,walk);

function walk(Event) {
    if(left) { 
            (...)
            char.x -= spdX;
            (...)
            }
```

I assume that the code worked up till now because, as the state of "left" constantly switched between "true" and "false", the **if** conditional was met repeatedly, leading the character to move. However, if I try to make it so that the conditional depends on "left" staying "true" for a certain time, the code becomes incompatible with itself.

In short, it brings the question of how to adapt the "KEY_[]" event listeners and the "walk" function to work, in using the getTimer() method, to work together.

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help section [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing more code here would be helpful

Comment: You need to listen to **KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN**, use **getTimer(...)** method to record the time (in milliseconds from the start of application) when that happened, then in **Event.ENTER_FRAME** handler do your thing repeatedly all until **KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP** kicks in.

Comment: You might also want to read this to picture the Flash application routine cycle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711218/4687633

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'll be adding more meaningful parts of the code to the post in an edit as soon as possible.

Comment: @Organis first of all, thanks again for the information provided. As suggested by Nathan Thomas, I added more lines of the code to better clarify how was my thought process and am open to suggestions for improving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that would be somehow self-explanatory .

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

var pressedKeyA:int;

// Never name variables and arguments with the same name
// as existing classes, however convenient that might seem.
function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        // Let's record the moment it was pressed.
        pressedKeyA = getTimer();
    }
}

function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        // Mark the key as not pressed.
        pressedKeyA = 0;
    }
}

function onFrame(e:Event):void
{
    // It is true if it is not 0.
    if (pressedKeyA)
    {
        // That's how long it has been pressed. In milliseconds.
        var pressedFor:int = getTimer() - pressedKeyA;

        // Change the position with regard to it.
        // For example 1 base + 1 per second.
        char.x -= 1 + pressedFor / 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I just need to change the code a little, but thank you very much indeed.